# JavaScript timer to count down from a certain time for a number of hours

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

I have created a countdown timer. The problem is, I am wanting it to count down from midnight clock `00:00:00` until clock `17:00:00`.

I have made the timer count down starting at `17 hours 00 minutes 00 seconds` and it works a treat, but I need a way to take off the time from `00:00:00` to present from the `17 hours`.

Here is my JS code

```
    function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var start = Date.now(),
        diff,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds;

    function timer() {
        // get the number of seconds that have elapsed since 
        // startTimer() was called
        diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);

        // Setting and displaying hours, minutes, seconds
        hours = (diff / 360) | 0;
        minutes = (diff / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (diff <= 0) {
            // add one second so that the count down starts at the full duration
            // example 17:00:00 not 16:59:59
            start = Date.now() + 1000;
        }
    };
    // don't want to wait a full second before the timer starts
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var timeLeft = 3600 * 17,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(timeLeft, display);
};
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div>Order by: <span id="time"></span> for Next Day Delivery.</div>
```

My thoughts were to get the `timeLeft = 3600 * 17` and take off the diff.

Comment: did you try `timeLeft = 3600 * 17 and take off the diff.` out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your corrected code : it was easier to save the timestamp of 17h of the current day (next day if we are after 17h) and compare it to the current timestamp. And to calculate the number of hours left, you have to divide the number of seconds by 3600 (60*60) and not 360

```js
function startTimer(display) {
    var date = new Date();
    var h17 = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 17);
    if(date.getHours() >= 17) {
        h17.setDate(h17.getDate()+1);
    }
    h17 = h17.getTime();
    var diff,
        hours,
        minutes,
        seconds;
    
    function timer() {
        diff = (((h17 - Date.now()) / 1000) | 0);
        
        // Setting and displaying hours, minutes, seconds
        hours = (diff / 3600) | 0;
        minutes = ((diff % 3600) / 60) | 0;
        seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
        
        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        
        display.textContent = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    };
    timer();
    setInterval(timer, 1000);
}
window.onload = function () {
    var timeLeft = 3600 * 17,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(display);
};
```

```html
<div>Order by: <span id="time"></span> for Next Day Delivery.</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1nfbff38/)

**PS :** I didn't test if the function work correctly after 17h but it should

Comment: There is an error on line 14 - diff = (((h17 - Date.now()) / 1000) | 0); I am getting the error message, "Object doesn't support this property or method: line 14". However the countdown figures are working perfectly.

Comment: Maybe you are on a old browser which didn't defined the method `now`: please fllow [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#Polyfill) to define it